# How to get current website_id in controller of Odoo

Tags: controller, odoo, odoo-website

There are two website ids in my website model -

id 1 has localhsot website and

id 2 has 0.0.0.0 website

I have written following controller to get data from backend to frontend -

```
class website(http.Controller):
@http.route(['/action_get_event_menu_content'], type='json', auth="public")
def get_event_content(self):
    website = request.env['website']
    website_ids = website.sudo().search([])
    #TODO: FILTER CURRENT WEBSITE
    value = website_ids.event_content
    return value
```

In this controller two ids get returned in website_ids = (1,2)

How do I get the current website id and put that in the search to get the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `'request.website'`.
It should give you the current website.

Comment: I get it worked by sending website=True in http:

'@http.route(['/action_get_event_menu_color'], type='json', auth="public", website=True)'

website_id = request.website.id worked.

Comment: yes.. right.. I didn't noticed that 'website=True' was not in your code.